# Use str_replace() to detect a string with a '+' string

Tags: r, string, replace

[image]

I wanted to clean the sales_method column such that 'email' would go under 'Email' and 'em + call' would go under 'Email + Call'. But when I use `str_replace_all()`, it was only able to detect and replace 'email'. Is there a way to replace the string with the '+' sign in it?

I tried

```
rep_str = c('email'='Email', 'em + call'='Email + Call')
sales_no_na$sales_method <- str_replace_all(sales_no_na$sales_method, rep_str)
```

which then ended up like this

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't share data as images - it makes it harder to for others to help you. Can you edit your question and add the data samples using `dput()` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to escape the plus sign using `\\`. Use

```
rep_str = c('email'='Email', 'em \\+ call'='Email + Call')

df$sales_method <- str_replace_all(df$sales_method, rep_str)

> df
# A tibble: 5 × 2
  count sales_method
  <dbl> <chr>       
1  6915 Email       
2  4781 Call        
3  2203 Email + Call
4    20 Email + Call
5     7 Email
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code

```r
df %>% mutate(sales_method=str_replace_all(sales_method, c('call'='Call','email'='Email','em'='Email'))) %>% 
  group_by(sales_method) %>% 
  summarise(count=sum(count)) %>% ungroup()
```

```r
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  sales_method count
  <chr>        <dbl>
1 Call          4781
2 Email         6922
3 Email + Call  2223
```